# Rewrite Rule - need guidance

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to do some redirecting to get some internal links to work but I'm having a complete block.

The url would be http://www.something.com/faqs/What_happens_if_I_move_home?

redirected to http://www.something.com/faqs/index/What_happens_if_I_move_home?

but it must look like the original url.  I'm sure there is a simple answer but rewrite rules and regex are a mystery to me at times.

I did try RewriteRule ^faqs(/.*)?$   /faqs/index$1 [R,L,NC]

amongst many others!

Comment: sorry I meant to add that is an example - there could be any string after the /faqs/ in the original url, I just need to redirect to the /index/  but without it showing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/faqs/index
RewriteRule ^faqs/(.*) /faqs/index/$1 [L,NC]
```